# how is smtp logged on a local server

Tags: smtp

I send emails using my web-based gmail accounts.  When I send and receive emails at my residence, is there a record of this in the server?  The letters smtp and ICID mean little to me, but I need to know in laymen's terms what sort of records, if any, of my emails can be accessed by logging into my server.  For example, are the email addresses listed in the server?  Is the content of the emails listed in the server?  Dates?  Anything?  I'm clueless.  Thank you very much.

Comment: If you use the web interface how would any kind of server that is yours be involved? Google keeps track of a lot of things (likely) you would have to look into their Privacy Policy and Terms of Use to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Each email sent and received pass through a server  (in this case a Gmail server).

The server registers and maintains a log of the sender and receiver of each email, besides other information as timestamp, and the connection to other servers.

As Gmail is a web mail server, the messages ARE in their servers. The web interface is only a way to visualize the emails.

So, they have not only the log, they have the messages and know their content.

In their privacy politics they say:

```
Our automated systems analyze your content (including emails) to provide you
personally relevant product features, such as customized search results,
tailored advertising, and spam and malware detection.
```